# PHP convert JSON object to string

Tags: php, json, file

I am making a quiz script. I want a "teacher" to be able to edit the questions. Originally, I tried to use mySQL but it was a bit difficult, so I decided to switch to a JSON file.

After doing some basic checks with PHP, I wrote this block of code

```
$json = array();
for ($x=1; $x < $count + 1; $x++) { 
    $q_and_a = array(
        "Question" => $_POST["q".$x],
        "Answer" => $_POST["a".$x]
        );
    array_push($json, $q_and_a);    
}
$encoded_array = json_encode($json);
// Delete JSON file, create new one and push encoded array into file
$json_file = 'questions.json';
unlink($json_file);
$handle = fopen($json_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$json_file);
fwrite($handle, $json_string) or die('Internal Sever Error');
```

After I got an internal server error, I realized that this is because the `$json` variable is an array; I need to convert it into a string and then insert it into the file. I first used `serialize()` but that just inserted some weird stuff into my file. How do I convert the json array into a string before moving it into the file?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Use `file_put_contents()` to save into a file

Comment: `$json_string` is never defined! A typo?

Comment: Presumably you want to "add" to the file, not replace the contents? It would be too bad if you lose 100 questions because you added one... Make sure you do this in a way that allows appending. Also - how do you expect to read this information back? That affects how to do this.

Comment: Another question: how did you define $count? It would definitely make sense to read all the current questions/ answers in from the file, then add new questions, and then save the entire thing back to file. That way you could even check if it's the same question (in which case maybe the answer changed).

Comment: `$count` is supposed to be for displaying the certain number of question and answer fields. I just wanted to put it as a variable, so if I needed to use it again, I could just reference it

Comment: So how do I just add to the file. I need to make sure that the JSON file appends correctly, with commas and the ending bracket

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code. It doen't use JSON but it still saves data into a file which is split up using `tab`

```
<?php 
$count=10;//whatever you defined it to
$qa = "";
for ($x=1; $x < $count + 1; $x++) { 
    $qa .= $_POST["q".$x]."\t".$_POST["a".$x]."\n";   
}
$json_file = 'file.txt';
unlink($json_file);
file_put_contents($qa);
?>

<?php
//to retrieve q&a
$qas = file('file.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$qas = explode("\t",$qas);
foreach($qas as $question => $answer)
{
    //your code 

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

fwrite($handle, $encoded_array) or die('Internal Sever Error');